# Not able to perform UPDATE query with sysdate - ORACLE

Tags: oracle, sql-update, unique-constraint, sysdate

I am trying to run the following, fairly simple, update statement in ORACLE.

```
UPDATE PROJECT_BUG_SNAPSHOTS
SET   SNAPSHOT_DATESTAMP = sysdate, 
      SNAPSHOT_TYPE      = P_SNAPSHOT_TYPE
      WHERE  PROJECT_ID  = P_PROJECT_ID
      AND    BUG_NO      = P_BUG_NO
      AND    BUG_STATUS  = P_BUG_STATUS;
```

It complains of unique constraint violation.

The PK comprises of `PROJECT_ID,BUG_NO,SNAPSHOT_DATESTAMP,SNAPSHOT_TYPE`.

The table structure is

```
PROJECT_ID          NUMBER
SNAPSHOT_DATESTAMP  DATE
SNAPSHOT_TYPE       VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
BUG_NO              NUMBER
BUG_STATUS          VARCHAR2(100 BYTE)
```

This is quite weird as sysdate should be different with each run and it should never hit the "unique constraint violation" error.

Comment: `sysdate` (being a `DATE`)  is only accurate to a second. So if you run multiple statements very quickly it is not unlikely you get the same value for `sysdate` twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary key is a combination of `PROJECT_ID`, `BUG_NO`, `SNAPSHOT_DATESTAMP`, and `SNAPSHOT_TYPE`. This means you allow (and probably have!) several rows with the same project id, bug number and snapshot type, but from different dates. Your `update` statement, will attempt to set all the snapshot dates of a given project, bug number and status to the same date (the current date), thus breaking the uniqueness and failing due to a constraint violation.